# mp3 to gsm for asterisk

Tags: mp3, converters, asterisk, gsm

In our application we allow user to upload audio file. currently we support .**wav** format and we use "**sox**" to convert the .wav file to gsm for asterisk. We would like to have **mp3** support as well. Any recommendation on how to get this done ?

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can still use `sox` to convert mp3 to gsm/sln/alaw/ulaw format files

Look at http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxformat.html for more info on formats sox support

Comment: It seems like my sox does not support mp3. do I miss something ?

Comment: they do support mp3, on ubuntu/debian try to `sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-mp3` or just install libsox-fmt-all

Comment: I have sox support for mp3. But I had some warning output with the following command :
sox infile.mp3 -r 8000 -c1 outfile.gsm
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 6 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 6 samples; decrease volume?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882125/reducing-removing-clipping-in-sox-when-converting-the-sample-rate

Answer (score 1):

Here is alot of info about asterisk file conversion.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sound+files

And for sure you can use asterisk(if it compiled with mp3 support)

```
asterisk -rx "file convert filename.mp3 filename.gsm"
```

If you want convert using sox, you have recompile sox with libmad support. Here is script:

```
cd /usr/src/

wget -c "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mad/libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz?modtime=1076976000&big_mirror=0"
wget -c 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mad/libid3tag-0.15.1b.tar.gz?modtime=1076976000&big_mirror=0'
wget -c "http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.3.2/sox-14.3.2.tar.gz/download"
wget -c http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.98.4/lame-3.98.4.tar.gz
wget -c "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mad/madplay-0.15.2b.tar.gz?modtime=1077580800&big_mirror=0"
CPU=4

for i in libid3tag libmad madplay lame sox 
do
cd /usr/src/
tar -xzf $i-*.gz

cd /usr/src/$i*
./configure;
make -j $CPU
make install
done;
echo /usr/local/lib/ >>/etc/ld.so.conf
ldconfig
sox
ln -s /usr/local/bin/sox /usr/bin/sox
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a software called "switch" from NCH Software and work very well to GSM conversion and with Elastix PBX. The only problem is on Elastix GUI the upload that dont work on System Records, so I had to upload using SCP aka SFTP over SSH.

http://www.nch.com.au/switch/

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:-

localhost*CLI> `help file convert`

Usage: file convert  
Convert from file_in to file_out. If an absolute path is not given, the
default Asterisk sounds directory will be used.

Example:
`file convert tt-monkeys.gsm tt-monkeys.ulaw`

Solution 2:- There are some online tool available which can work for you.
https://convertio.co/
It can convert your file in almost 20 formats. e.g gsm, wav, cdma,wma etc.