# What's the best way to eliminate audio clipping with sox?

Tags: audio, sox

I am trying to convert some audio files to a raw format for machine learning and I need to ensure that clipping does not occur because I do not want it to contaminate my dataset.

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890216/2341218), but unfortunately the solutions did not work for me.

Several options have been proposed to help mitigate this problem.

The --norm option does not appear to work very well ...

```
$ for name in *.au; do sox --norm ${name} -c 1 -r 44100 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
```

The -v 0.99 option does not appear to work very well:

```
$ for name in *.au; do sox -v 0.99 ${name} -c 1 -r 44100 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 11 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 8 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 12 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 9 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 6 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 5 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 10 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 11 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 3 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 3 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 2 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 2 samples; decrease volume?
ubuntu@ip-10-217-154-40:~/data/genre/genres/blues$ for name in *.au;
```

The -G option seems to work best. However, even with this option some clipping occurs.

```
$ for name in *.au; do sox -G ${name} -c 1 -r 41000 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 2 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
```

Combining -G and --norm did worse than using either individually ...

```
$ for name in *.au; do sox -G --norm ${name} -c 1 -r 44100 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 2 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
```

**UPDATE: Further reducing the volume seems to eliminate the clipping.**
Is this the best solution?

```
$ for name in *.au; do sox -G -v 0.95 ${name} -c 1 -r 44100 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 1 samples; decrease volume?

$ for name in *.au; do sox -G -v 0.9 ${name} -c 1 -r 44100 --bits 8 ${name}.mono-sr41000-ss8.raw; done
```